# Stylegan2-ada-pytorch Environment

Tags: pytorch, generative-adversarial-network

## The workable environment

- cuda10.2
- cudnn7.6.5
- visual studio2019
- pytorch1.10.1+cu102
- torchvisoin0.11.2+cu102
- torchaudio0.10.1+cu102
- python3.8

## The mistaks before

Describe the bug

When I try to run the official command:

```
python generate.py --outdir=out --trunc=1 --seeds=85,265,297,849 --network=https://nvlabs-fi-cdn.nvidia.com/stylegan2-ada-pytorch/pretrained/metfaces.pkl
```

It works, but the result performs like this:

[image: seed 85]

Terminal shows these:

> ```
> Setting up PyTorch plugin "bias_act_plugin"... Done.
> Setting up PyTorch plugin "upfirdn2d_plugin"... Done.
> Generating image for seed 85 (1/4) ...
> Generating image for seed 265 (2/4) ...
> Generating image for seed 297 (3/4) ...
> Generating image for seed 849 (4/4) ...
> ```

Environment

- torch=1.10.1+cu113
- cuda=11.3
- cudnn=8.2.1
- python=3.8
- visual studio2019

Could you please tell me how can I solve this problem.

Comment: Thank you for your kind help@Shai. I had rebuilt my environment yesterday, and this time it shows the right images. I leave my environment here, hope it can help someone